# How I can make ChoiceDiIalog with multiple ChoiceBoxes in JavaFX 8

Tags: dialog, javafx-8

I can use

```
ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog();
dialog.showAndWait();
```

but i'll have only one choiceBox to use, and I need 3 of this in one dialog. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
public void showAndWait(Window owner) throws IOException {
    Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/customDialog.fxml")));
    dialog.getDialogPane().setHeaderText("text");
    ButtonType confirm = new ButtonType("ok", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    ButtonType cancel = new ButtonType("cansel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(cancel, confirm);
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    dialog.setTitle("title");
    dialog.initOwner(owner);
    dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

Looks nice, i make class with this method, and use it class like controller to fxml, so now I can easily use any controls without any troubles

Comment: and what is "customDialog.fxml" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build yourself a custom dialog, using the tutorial at http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

I adapted their custom dialog for three dropdowns; in my case to merge two custom POJO camera objects with make, model and serial number. Feel free to adapt and use my code below.

```
Set<String> makes = new HashSet<>();
toMerge.stream().forEach((c) -> {
    if (c.getMake()!=null && !c.getMake().isEmpty()) {
        makes.add(c.getMake());
    }
});
if (makes.isEmpty()) {
    makes.add("UNKNOWN");
}

Set<String> models = new HashSet<>();
toMerge.stream().forEach((c) -> {
    if (c.getModel()!=null && !c.getModel().isEmpty()) {
        models.add(c.getModel());
    }
});
if (models.isEmpty()) {
    models.add("UNKNOWN");
}

Set<String> serials = new HashSet<>();
toMerge.stream().forEach((c) -> {
    if (c.getSerial()!=null && !c.getSerial().isEmpty()) {
        serials.add(c.getSerialNumber());
    }
});
if (serials.isEmpty()) {
    serials.add("UNKNOWN");
}

Dialog<HashMap<String, String>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.setTitle("Merge cameras");
dialog.setHeaderText("Please select the values for the merged camera. You can modify the merged camera later");

// Set the button types.
ButtonType mergeButtonType = new ButtonType("Merge", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(mergeButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));

ComboBox<String> makesBox = new ComboBox<>();
makes.stream().forEach((make) -> {
    makesBox.getItems().add(make);
});
makesBox.setValue(makes.iterator().next());

ComboBox<String> modelsBox = new ComboBox<>();
models.stream().forEach((model) -> {
    modelsBox.getItems().add(model);
});
modelsBox.setValue(models.iterator().next());

ComboBox<String> serialsBox = new ComboBox<>();
serials.stream().forEach((serial) -> {
    serialsBox.getItems().add(serial);
});
serialsBox.setValue(serials.iterator().next());

grid.add(new Label("Make:"), 0, 0);
grid.add(makesBox, 1, 0);
grid.add(new Label("Model:"), 0, 1);
grid.add(modelsBox, 1, 1);
grid.add(new Label("Serial number:"), 0, 2);
grid.add(serialsBox, 1, 2);

dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

// Convert the result to the desired data structure
dialog.setResultConverter(dialogButton -> {
    if (dialogButton == mergeButtonType) {
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("make", makesBox.getValue());
        result.put("model", modelsBox.getValue());
        result.put("serial", serialsBox.getValue());
        return result;
    }
    return null;
});

Optional<HashMap<String, String>> result = dialog.showAndWait();

result.ifPresent(r -> {
    logger.debug("{}", r);
    //TODO: handle result
});
```